# unable to instantiate a PackageManager

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I am making a application which relies on a class which uses a BroadCastReceiver so that I can catch when a application is installed and uninstalled. The intent is received just fine, and the code in onReceive executes as it should. Hoever, the problem I am having is that I get a a error message when I try to instantiate a new PackageManger. The error is: "Cannot instantiate the type PackageManager".
I've pretty much tried all variations, but I just can't get it to work.

my code:

```
package com.my.package;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;

public class PackageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Uri datauri         = intent.getData(); 
        String uri          = datauri.toString();
        PackageManager pm   = new PackageManager();
        //pm.getApplicationInfo(uri);   //broken
        test(datauri);                  //works fine
    }//end method

    public void test(Uri uri){
        Log.d("test", "data: "+uri);
    }//end method
}// end class
```

Comment: Usually the stacktrace is several lines, can you post also the full stacktrace, maybe there is some meaningful info in the rest of the lines.

Comment: @ilomambo: thanks for the reply, actually I didn't even bother to run the code, as it wouldn't have worked. I used imran khan's solution, this works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
PackageManager pm= context.getPackageManager(); 
List<ApplicationInfo> applicationInfos = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
....
```

instead of

```
PackageManager pm   = new PackageManager();
```